# scrapy: Defining crawler settings

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to override some settings for a crawler being called in a script, but these settings seems not to take effect:

```
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from someproject.spiders import SomeSpider

spider = SomeSpider()
overrides = {
    'LOG_ENABLED': True,
    'LOG_STDOUT': True,
}
settings = get_project_settings()
settings.overrides.update(overrides)
log.start()
crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings)
crawler.install()
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
```

And in the spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class SomeSpider(BaseSpider):

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_urls = [ 'http://somedomain.com' ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print 'some test' # won't print anything
        exit(0) # will normally exit failing the crawler
```

By defining `LOG_ENABLED` and `LOG_STDOUT`, I expect to see the "some test" string being printed in the log. Also, I can't seem to redirect the log to a `LOG_FILE` among some other settings I've tried.

I must be doing something wrong...
Please help. =D

Answer (score 0):

use `log.msg('some test')` to print the log

Answer (score 0):

You may need to start Twisted's reactor after starting the crawler:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
#...other imports...

#...setup crawler...
crawler.start()
reactor.run()
```

Related question/more code: [Scrapy crawl from script always blocks script execution after scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777910/scrapy-crawl-from-script-always-blocks-script-execution-after-scraping)