# How to call Scrapy Spider through a Django App

Tags: python, django, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm having trouble calling a scrapy spider in my django view. How can I do this?
I tried to follow this tutorial http://tryolabs.com/Blog/2011/09/27/calling-scrapy-python-script/ but did not work in the import settings.

Comment: Please post the full error message. Thank you.

Comment: Use [django dynamic scraper](https://github.com/holgerd77/django-dynamic-scraper).

Comment: That script is somewhat out-of-date and scrapy has changed a lot since then. Try out the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777910/scrapy-crawl-from-script-always-blocks-script-execution-after-scraping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error is coming from

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
```

it's likely because scrapy simply can't find the settings file it's expecting.  Since it's customary in Django to use `settings` for django's own configuration, it would be clearest if you don't use that term.

You can specify your scrapy settings within your Django settings:

```
"""settings.py"""
# stuff

SCRAPY_SETTINGS = {
    ... # put your usual scrapy keys and values here
}

# more stuff
```

Then, instead of importing `scrapy.conf.settings`, you can instead use:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

and where you reference scrapy settings in your script, you should change the argument to CrawlerProcess to settings.SCRAPY_SETTINGS

```
self.crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings.SCRAPY_SETTINGS)
```

If you have any further trouble, please post the full error you're getting and the code for your view.

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternatively, you can create the settings object like so:

```
from scrapy.settings import Settings
settings = Settings()
settings.setmodule('path.to.scrapy.settings', priority='project')
```