# Scrapy Very Basic Example

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I have Python Scrapy installed on my mac and I was trying to follow the v[ery first example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/intro/overview.html#run-the-spider-to-extract-the-data) on their web.

They were trying to run the command:

```
scrapy crawl mininova.org -o scraped_data.json -t json
```

I don't quite understand what does this mean? looks like scrapy turns out to be a separate program. And I don't think they have a command called crawl. In the example, they have a paragraph of code, which is the definition of the class MininovaSpider and the TorrentItem. I don't know where these two classes should go to, go to the same file and what is the name of this python file?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to follow this example on there web and scrape minonova's project.

Comment: I pushed some old scrapy scripts to github this evening if you want to use them as example: https://github.com/dreamcc/Scrapy-Spiders

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56517504/2248627)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may have better luck looking through [the tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/intro/tutorial.html#intro-tutorial) first, as opposed to the "Scrapy at a glance" webpage.

The tutorial implies that Scrapy is, in fact, a separate program.

Running the command `scrapy startproject tutorial` will create a folder called `tutorial` several files already set up for you.

For example, in my case, the modules/packages `items`, `pipelines`, `settings` and `spiders` have been added to the root package `tutorial` .

```
tutorial/
    scrapy.cfg
    tutorial/
        __init__.py
        items.py
        pipelines.py
        settings.py
        spiders/
            __init__.py
            ...
```

The `TorrentItem` class would be placed inside `items.py`, and the `MininovaSpider` class would go inside the `spiders` folder.

Once the project is set up, the command-line parameters for Scrapy appear to be fairly straightforward. They take the form:

```
scrapy crawl <website-name> -o <output-file> -t <output-type>
```

Alternatively, if you want to run scrapy without the overhead of creating a project directory, you can use the [runspider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/topics/commands.html#std:command-runspider) command:

```
scrapy runspider my_spider.py
```

Answer (score 60):

**TL;DR:** see [Self-contained minimum example script to run scrapy](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/fc1527d6d9492b59c610).

First of all, having a normal Scrapy project with a separate `.cfg`, `settings.py`, `pipelines.py`, `items.py`, `spiders` package etc is a recommended way to keep and handle your web-scraping logic. It provides a modularity, separation of concerns that keeps things organized, clear and testable.

If you are following the [official Scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) to create a project, you are running web-scraping via a special `scrapy` command-line tool:

```
scrapy crawl myspider
```

---

But, `Scrapy` also *provides an API* to [run crawling from a script](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script).

There are several key concepts that should be mentioned:

- [`Settings` class](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.settings.Settings) - basically a key-value "container" which is initialized with [default built-in values](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#topics-settings-ref)
- [`Crawler` class](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.Crawler) - the main class that acts like a glue for all the different components involved in web-scraping with Scrapy
- Twisted `reactor` - since Scrapy is built-in on top of `twisted` asynchronous networking library - to start a crawler, we need to put it inside the [Twisted Reactor](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/reactor-basics.html), which is in simple words, an event loop:

> The reactor is the core of the event loop within Twisted – the loop which drives applications using Twisted. The event loop is a programming construct that waits for and
>   dispatches events or messages in a program. It works by calling some
>   internal or external “event provider”, which generally blocks until an
>   event has arrived, and then calls the relevant event handler
>   (“dispatches the event”). The reactor provides basic interfaces to a
>   number of services, including network communications, threading, and
>   event dispatching.

Here is a basic and simplified process of running Scrapy from script:

- create a `Settings` instance (or use [`get_project_settings()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170682/running-scrapy-from-script-not-including-pipeline) to use existing settings):

  ```
  settings = Settings()  # or settings = get_project_settings()
  ```
- instantiate `Crawler` with `settings` instance passed in:

  ```
  crawler = Crawler(settings)
  ```
- instantiate a spider (this is what it is all about eventually, right?):

  ```
  spider = MySpider()
  ```
- configure signals. This is an important step if you want to have a post-processing logic, [collect stats](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html) or, at least, to ever finish crawling since the twisted `reactor` needs to be stopped manually. Scrapy docs suggest to stop the `reactor` in the [`spider_closed` signal](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.spider_closed) handler:

> Note that you will also have to shutdown the Twisted reactor yourself
>   after the spider is finished. This can be achieved by connecting a
>   handler to the signals.spider_closed signal.

```
def callback(spider, reason):
    stats = spider.crawler.stats.get_stats()
    # stats here is a dictionary of crawling stats that you usually see on the console        

    # here we need to stop the reactor
    reactor.stop()

crawler.signals.connect(callback, signal=signals.spider_closed)
```

- configure and start crawler instance with a spider passed in:

  ```
  crawler.configure()
  crawler.crawl(spider)
  crawler.start()
  ```
- optionally start [logging](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html):

  ```
  log.start()
  ```
- start the reactor - this would block the script execution:

  ```
  reactor.run()
  ```

Here is an example self-contained script that is using [`DmozSpider` spider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider) and involves [item loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) with [input and output processors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#input-and-output-processors) and [item pipelines](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html):

```
import json

from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose, TakeFirst
from scrapy import log, signals, Spider, Item, Field
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from twisted.internet import reactor


# define an item class
class DmozItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
    desc = Field()


# define an item loader with input and output processors
class DmozItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    desc_out = Join()


# define a pipeline
class JsonWriterPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('items.jl', 'wb')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item


# define a spider
class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            loader = DmozItemLoader(DmozItem(), selector=sel, response=response)
            loader.add_xpath('title', 'a/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('link', 'a/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('desc', 'text()')
            yield loader.load_item()


# callback fired when the spider is closed
def callback(spider, reason):
    stats = spider.crawler.stats.get_stats()  # collect/log stats?

    # stop the reactor
    reactor.stop()


# instantiate settings and provide a custom configuration
settings = Settings()
settings.set('ITEM_PIPELINES', {
    '__main__.JsonWriterPipeline': 100
})

# instantiate a crawler passing in settings
crawler = Crawler(settings)

# instantiate a spider
spider = DmozSpider()

# configure signals
crawler.signals.connect(callback, signal=signals.spider_closed)

# configure and start the crawler
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()

# start logging
log.start()

# start the reactor (blocks execution)
reactor.run()
```

Run it in a usual way:

```
python runner.py
```

and observe items exported to `items.jl` with the help of the pipeline:

```
{"desc": "", "link": "/", "title": "Top"}
{"link": "/Computers/", "title": "Computers"}
{"link": "/Computers/Programming/", "title": "Programming"}
{"link": "/Computers/Programming/Languages/", "title": "Languages"}
{"link": "/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/", "title": "Python"}
...
```

Gist is available here (feel free to improve):

- [Self-contained minimum example script to run scrapy](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/fc1527d6d9492b59c610)

---

Notes:

If you define `settings` by instantiating a `Settings()` object - you'll get all the defaults Scrapy settings. But, if you want to, for example, configure an existing pipeline, or configure a `DEPTH_LIMIT` or tweak any other setting, you need to either set it in the script via [`settings.set()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.settings.Settings.set) (as demonstrated in the example):

```
pipelines = {
    'mypackage.pipelines.FilterPipeline': 100,
    'mypackage.pipelines.MySQLPipeline': 200
}
settings.set('ITEM_PIPELINES', pipelines, priority='cmdline')
```

or, use an existing `settings.py` with all the custom settings preconfigured:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

settings = get_project_settings()
```

---

Other useful links on the subject:

- [How to run Scrapy from within a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437402/how-to-run-scrapy-from-within-a-python-script)
- [Confused about running Scrapy from within a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564305/confused-about-running-scrapy-from-within-a-python-script)
- [scrapy run spider from script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662689/scrapy-run-spider-from-script)

Comment: Can we manually invoke a pipeline for post-processing the items this way?

Comment: Thanks a lot @alecxe for this detailed answer! In order that your example code is really 100% self-contained and can be used very easily for `Scrapy` learners, could you add an example of very simple spider? (For example crawling http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/)

Comment: @pad added a note about using custom settings (which include configuring pipelines). Thanks, good point.

Comment: @Basj I'm actually thinking about making a sample github project which would include a simple script to run Scrapy. Hope will have time for it this week. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes @alecxe this would be nice, or even a gist. Goal: simplest and shortest code possible to run a crawler with `python mycrawler.py` :) (Self-contained file)

Comment: @Basj ok, done - please see the update. Feedback? :)

Comment: @pad also see the update - in the example I'm using the pipeline defined in the same file.

Comment: @alecxe, this is great, but if I wanted to run multiple crawls in parallel processes, would each of those need their own reactor?