# A web crawler in a self-contained python file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have found lots of `Scrapy` tutorials (such as [this good tutorial](http://amaral-lab.org/blog/quick-introduction-web-crawling-using-scrapy-part-)) that all need the steps listed below. The result is a *project*, with lots of files (`project.cfg` + some `.py` files + a specific folder structure).

**How to make the steps (listed below) work as a self-contained python file that can be run with** `python mycrawler.py` ?

*(instead of a full project with lots of files, some .cfg files, etc., and having to use `scrapy crawl myproject -o myproject.json`... by the way, it seems that `scrapy` is a new shell command? is this true?)*

*Note: [here could be an answer to this question](http://snipplr.com/view/67012/selfcontained-script-to-crawl-a-site-updated-scrapy-130dev/) but unfortunately it is deprecated and no longer works.*

---

1) Create a new scrapy project with `scrapy startproject myproject`

2) Define the data structure with `Item` like this:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
    class MyItem(Item):
        title = Field() 
        link = Field()
        ...
```

3) Define the crawler with

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "myproject"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"] 
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        ...
```

4) Run with:

```
scrapy crawl myproject -o myproject.json
```

Comment: How to make the steps (listed below) work as a self-contained python file that can be run with python mycrawler.py ?

Can you explain this statement briefly..

Comment: @vikasdumca the fact is that these tutorial (http://amaral-lab.org/blog/quick-introduction-web-crawling-using-scrapy-part-) don't show how to make a runnable-in-one-script code. I would like to be able to do http://amaral-lab.org/blog/quick-introduction-web-crawling-using-scrapy-part-  in one single file `testcrawler.py` and be able to run it with `python testcrawler.py` instead of having to run `scrapy ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run scrapy spiders as a single script without starting a project by using [`runspider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#std:command-runspider)
Is this what you wanted?

```
#myscript.py
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy import Spider

class MyItem(Item):
    title = Field() 
    link = Field()

class MySpider(Spider):

     start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']
     name = 'samplespider'

     def parse(self, response):
          item = MyItem()
          item['title'] = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
          item['link'] = response.url
          yield item
```

Now you can run this with `scrapy runspider myscript.py -o out.json`

Comment: Thanks @pad. I would like to be able to run it with `python myscript.py`. What do I need to add to be able to run it like this?

Comment: @Basj  look at the very comprehensive answer [by alecxe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27744766/4065855)

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy is not unix command  it just executable like python,javac,gcc etc.
bcz u are using framework for this you have to use command given provided by 
framework. 
one thing you can do is create a bash script and simply execute whenever you need or execute it from some other program program.

you can write crawler using urllib3 its simple