# Scrapy code can't accept arguments in Python script

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm attempting to run Scrapy within a Python script. Here's the relevant code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class PostSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "post crawler"
    allowed_domains = ['test.com']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PostSpider, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        url = kwargs.get('url')
        print(url)
        self.start_urls = ['https://www.test.com/wp-json/test/2.0/posts' + url]

    def parse(self, response):
        post = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        post = post["content"]
        return post

posts = GA.retrieve(TIA.start_date, TIA.end_date, "content type auto")

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
}) 

for post in posts:
    post_url = post[2]
    process.crawl(PostSpider(url=post_url))
    process.start()
```

I'm attempting to follow the guidelines [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705595/pass-argument-to-scrapy-spider-within-a-python-script) somewhat. However, I can't get it to work. Here's the error message I received:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2016-03-25 20:49:43 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text_analysis.py", line 48, in <module>
    process.crawl(PostSpider(url=post_url))
  File "/Users/terence/TIA/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 163, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/terence/TIA/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 167, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/terence/TIA/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Users/terence/TIA/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Users/terence/TIA/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 71, in crawl
    self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/terence/TIA/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 94, in _create_spider
    return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/terence/TIA/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 50, in from_crawler
    spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "text_analysis.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.start_urls = ['https://www.techinasia.com/wp-json/techinasia/2.0/posts' + url]
builtins.TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
2016-03-25 20:49:43 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
/xiaomi-still-got-it-bitches
2016-03-25 20:49:43 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats', 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The call of `process.crawl()` must be

```
process.crawl(PostSpider, url=post_url)
```

as the [definition](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess) is

> crawl(crawler_or_spidercls, *args, **kwargs)

It expects the spider class (not the instantiated object) as the first argument. All following positional and keyword arguments (`*args, **kwargs`) are passed on to the spider init function.

Comment: Was looking for this for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`CrawlerProcess.crawl`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess.crawl) expects a `Spider` **class**, not a `Spider` instance.

You should pass arguments like this:

```
process.crawl(PostSpider, url=post_url)
```