# Iron worker and scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, iron.io

I am trying to create an iron.io worker using scrapy.

According to iron.io we need to place all the dependencies for the code in the worker itself.

I have created a folder called `module` which will have all the 3rd party modules and installed scrapy via pip.

```
pip install scrapy -t module/
```

When trying to run scrapy via `python module/scrapy/__init__.py` I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "module/scrapy/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    __version__ = pkgutil.get_data(__package__, 'VERSION').decode('ascii').strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 578, in get_data
    loader = get_loader(package)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 464, in get_loader
    return find_loader(fullname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 474, in find_loader
    for importer in iter_importers(fullname):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 424, in iter_importers
    if fullname.startswith('.'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: It is a strange way to run scrapy, why are you doing it this way?

Comment: may be you could let me know how I can do the same for scrapy will not be installed via pip on the iron worker .

Comment: I just meant why are you running  scrapy with `python module/scrapy/__init__.py`?

Comment: else how could you run scrapy then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably be better off using Scrapy from your IronWorker code rather than calling it from the command line, just like it has on the front page of http://scrapy.org/ or in the tutorial: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/intro/tutorial.html

To use this in IronWorker, after you've done the pip install, be sure to add:

```
pip 'scrapy'
```

to your .worker file. Then in your worker script, you'd import it:

```
import scrapy
```

Then use it like it says in the tutorial link above.

Comment: I like @alecxe answer how to run scrapy from script . Your answer is  correct regarding how to install scrapy on iron worker.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `Scrapy` executable available, you can run `Scrapy` via `cmdline`:

```
python module/scrapy/cmdline.py
```

You can also *run `Scrapy` from script*. [Here is a very detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838494/scrapy-very-basic-example/27744766#27744766).

Comment: I like your answer how to run scrapy from script. As we can install scrapy on worker via pip, I feel it will be more accurate. Thanks!

Comment: @HariKT appreciate it, thank you. Happy web-scraping.