# How we can get List of urls after crawling website from scrapy in costom python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy

I am working with a script where i need to crawl websites, need to crawl only base_url site. Anyone who has pretty good idea how i can launch scarpy in custom python scripts and get urls link in list?

Comment: FYI, here is [a detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838494/scrapy-very-basic-example/27744766#27744766) about running Scrapy from script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Scrapy commands from an external library by adding scrapy.commands section into entry_points in the setup.py.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='scrapy-mymodule',
  entry_points={
    'scrapy.commands': [
      'my_command=my_scrapy_module.commands:MyCommand',
    ],
  },
 )
```

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/experimental/index.html?highlight=library#add-commands-using-external-libraries

Also see [Scrapy Very Basic Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838494/scrapy-very-basic-example/27744766#27744766).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file to pass the urls from scrapy to your python script.

Or you can print the urls with a mark in your scrapy, and use your python script to catch the stdout of your scrapy.Then parse it to list.