# Scrapy -- When calling scrapy from script, how to return a dictionary to the process immediately, instead of export to json file

Tags: python, json, scrapy

[The official tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) specifies the way on how to call scrapy within python script

By changing the following setting attributes:

```
settings.overrides['FEED_URI'] = output_path
settings.overrides['FEED_FORMAT'] = 'json'
```

I am able to store the data scraped in a json file.

However, I'm trying to process and return the data scraped immediately within the function I defined. Hence, other functions can call this wrapper function in order to scrap some websites.

I figure there must be some settings I can play with `FEED_URI`, but I am not sure. Any advice will be appreciated deeply!

Comment: Create a pipeline? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27744766/771848) (unofficial tutorial).

Answer (score 2):

Feed exports are meant to serialize the data you've scraped (see [feed export documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-format)). What you are trying to do doesn't involve serialization.

What you want to do instead is create a [pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#topics-item-pipeline). Scrapy will pass scraped `Items` to the pipeline. They are dictionaries, and you can do whatever you want with them.