# Scrapy: ImportError: No module named project_name.settings

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

i'm trying to make a script that runs many spiders but i'm getting `ImportError: No module named project_name.settings`

my script looks like this:

```
import os
os.system("scrapy crawl spider1")
os.system("scrapy crawl spider2")
....
os.system("scrapy crawl spiderN")
```

My settings.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for project_name
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only the most important settings by
# default. All the other settings are documented here:
#
#     http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#

BOT_NAME = 'project_name'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'project_name.pipelines.project_namePipelineToJSON': 300,
    'project_name.pipelines.project_namePipelineToDB': 800
}

SPIDER_MODULES = ['project_name.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'project_name.spiders'

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'project_name (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'
```

And my spiders look like any normal spider, quite simple ones actually...

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from Projectname.items import ProjectnameItem

class ProjectnameSpiderClass(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Projectname"
    allowed_domains = ["Projectname.com"]

    start_urls = ["...urls..."]


    def parse(self, response):
        item = ProjectnameItem()
```

I gave them generic names but you get the idea, is there a way to solve this error?

Comment: Please see this relevant [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27744766/771848) providing a detailed explanation on how to run Scrapy from script.

Comment: @alecxe okay i'm using that template from the GIST, is there a way to run multiple spiders from that script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 2018:

You need to run the spider from the project folder, meaning that the `os.system("scrapy crawl spider1")` has to be run from the folder with the `spider1`.

Or you can do as I did in the past, putting all the code in a single file (old answer, not recommended by me anymore, but still useful and decent solution)

> Well, in case someone comes up to this question I finally used a heavily modified version of this https://gist.github.com/alecxe/fc1527d6d9492b59c610 provided by alexce in another question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Could you please make a gist of your modified version? I think the sample I've provided needs an improvement..