# Scrapy put two spiders in single file

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written two spiders in single file. When I ran `scrapy runspider two_spiders.py`, only the first Spider was executed. How can I run both of them without splitting the file into two files.

two_spiders.py:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # first spider definition
    ...

class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # second spider definition
    ...
```

Comment: Why do you want them in one file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's read the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html):

> **Running multiple spiders in the same process**
>
> By default, Scrapy runs a
>   single spider per process when you run `scrapy crawl`. However, Scrapy
>   supports running multiple spiders per process using the [internal API](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#topics-api).
>
> Here is an example that runs multiple spiders simultaneously:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your first spider definition
    ...

class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your second spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider1)
process.crawl(MySpider2)
process.start() # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```

(there are few more examples in the documentation)

From your question it is not clear how have you put two spiders into one file. It was not enough to concatenate content of two files with single spiders.

Try to do what is written in the documentation. Or at least show us your code. Without it we can't help you.

Comment: Please see my update. And I want to run it using 'scrapy runspider'.

Comment: It will throw `twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable` even if I crawl only one spider.

Comment: Why is it critical for you to use `scrapy runspider`? And why don't you want to run pair of spiders as it is written in the documentation?

Comment: I am new bee in scrapy and only know `runspider`. I should have read documentation carefully first. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **full Scrapy project** with 2 spiders in **one file**.

```
# quote_spiders.py
import json
import string

import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class TextCleaningPipeline(object):

    def _clean_text(self, text):
        text = text.replace('“', '').replace('”', '')
        table = str.maketrans({key: None for key in string.punctuation})
        clean_text = text.translate(table)
        return clean_text.lower()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item['text'] = self._clean_text(item['text'])
        return item


class JsonWriterPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open(spider.settings['JSON_FILE'], 'a')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item


class QuoteItem(Item):
    text = Field()
    author = Field()
    tags = Field()
    spider = Field()


class QuotesSpiderOne(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes1"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/', ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            item = QuoteItem()
            item['text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').get()
            item['author'] = quote.css('small.author::text').get()
            item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall()
            item['spider'] = self.name
            yield item


class QuotesSpiderTwo(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes2"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/', ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            item = QuoteItem()
            item['text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').get()
            item['author'] = quote.css('small.author::text').get()
            item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall()
            item['spider'] = self.name
            yield item


if __name__ == '__main__':
    settings = dict()
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    settings['HTTPCACHE_ENABLED'] = True
    settings['JSON_FILE'] = 'items.jl'
    settings['ITEM_PIPELINES'] = dict()
    settings['ITEM_PIPELINES']['__main__.TextCleaningPipeline'] = 800
    settings['ITEM_PIPELINES']['__main__.JsonWriterPipeline'] = 801

    process = CrawlerProcess(settings=settings)
    process.crawl(QuotesSpiderOne)
    process.crawl(QuotesSpiderTwo)
    process.start()
```

Install Scrapy and run the script

```
$ pip install Scrapy
$ python quote_spiders.py
```

No other file is needed.

This example coupled with graphical debugger of pycharm/vscode  can help understand scrapy workflow and make debugging easier.