# Python Scrapy re-crawl same URL with same spider and different user input of depth

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

If I call this code in a method more than once, it fails but no error is displayed in the Terminal. It only runs once. Is it not possible to recrawl with the same spider twice?
It fails at the line reactor.run() and the spider never runs the second time it's invoked, but there is no error in the logs.

```
def crawlSite(self):

    self.mySpider = MySpider()
    self.mySpider.setCrawlFolder(self.website)

    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings.set('DEPTH_LIMIT', self.depth)

    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(self.mySpider)
    crawler.start()

    log.start(logfile="results.log", loglevel=log.ERROR, crawler=crawler, logstdout=False) #log.DEBUG

    reactor.run() # the script will block here until the spider_closed signal was sent
```

This is the MySpider class

```
 class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "mysite"
    crawlFolder = ""
    crawlFolder1 = ""
    crawlFolder2 = ""
    allowed_domains = ["mysite.ca"]

    start_urls = [  "http://www.mysite.ca" ]

    rules = [ Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'^http://www.mysite.ca/',), unique=True), callback='parse_item', follow=True), ]

    def parse_item(self, response):

        #store data in a website item object
        item = WebsiteClass()
        item['title'] = response.selector.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        item['body'] = response.selector.xpath('//body').extract()
        item['url'] = response.url



        ...
```

Then I have a SetupClass that calls crawlSite() in CrawlerClass

```
self.crawlerClass.crawlSite()
```

Comment: We need full code to see more

Comment: Is the close signal working? Maybe you should implement it via the dispatcher? Check  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777910/scrapy-crawl-from-script-always-blocks-script-execution-after-scraping/14802526#14802526)...